# removing unused DOM elements for performance

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a single page application. When the page is initially served, it contains many DOM elements that contain json strings that I'm injecting into the page.

When the page loads on the client, the first thing that happens is that these DOM elements are parsed from json to javascript objects and then they're never used again.

Would there be a performance benefit into deleting them from the DOM and reducing its size? I haven't found any conclusive data about this aspect. For info, these elements are about 500K in size.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You could set up some test cases and do time trials.

Comment: What elements are they? If they're not in the body, then it might not really be necessary to remove them - once the DOM is parsed, it's parsed.

Comment: I have a similar case where I keep the HTML for temporary popups or tooltips in the DOM. It is beneficial to clean them up?

Comment: @TheZ: I was wondering what kind of test I could do?

Comment: @Dancrumb: of course they're in the body!

Comment: **500K** good grief.  We're talking about `<script>` tags with a phony non-JavaScript "type" here I presume. If so, then if you pull them all into global JavaScript I can't help but imagine it'd free up space if you delete them.

Comment: @Pointy: it's unreal isn't it?

Comment: @frenchie: no 'of course' about it. They could be in the head as `<script>` elements.

Comment: @Pointy: no, we're talking about <div id="SomeID">huge json string</div> and then var SomeObject = JSON.parse($('#SomeID').text());

Comment: @Dancrumb: ah yes, I see what you mean. No, they're in the body, in divs.

Comment: @frenchie ah well if I were you I'd put them in `<script type="text/json">` blocks instead - that way you keep the browser from having to think about the contents, and also prevent any possible problems from HTML metacharacters in the middle of your JSON.

Comment: @Pointy: ok I like this suggestion. Let me think about it a bit; may be you should post it as answer actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of whether you pull the JSON from the DOM, you might consider this technique for including your JSON objects:

```
<script type='text/json' id='whatever'>
  { "some": "json" }
</script>
```

Browsers will completely ignore the contents of those scripts (except of course for embedded strings that look like `</script>`, which it occurs to me as things a JSON serializer might want to somehow deal with), so you don't risk running into proplems with embedded ampersands and things.  That's probably a performance win in and of itself: the browser probably has an easier time looking for the end of the `<script>` block than it does looking through stuff that it thinks is actual content. You can get the content verbatim with `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Perhaps just semantics, but you should recommend the `text` property rather than `innerHTML` since script elements don't contain markup. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I agree but I'm not sure that works in all browsers. It might.

Answer (score 4):

> Would there be a performance benefit into deleting them from the DOM
>   and reducing its size?

In terms of the performance of the DOM, generally, the less you interact with your DOM, the better.

Remember that your selectors traverse the dom, so if you use inefficient selectors, it will be  poor performance no matter what, but if you're selecting elements by ID rather than class or attribute wherever possible, you can squeeze good performance out of the page, regardless of whether you've deleted those extraneous markup items.

> When the page is initially served, it contains many DOM elements that
>   contain json strings that I'm injecting into the page.... For info,
>   these elemnts are about 500K in size.

In terms of page load, your performance is suffering already from having to transfer all of that data. if you can find a way to transfer the json only, it could only help. Deleting after the fact wouldn't be solving this particular problem, though.

Comment: Ok, upvoted for your insights. I decided to move the json strings to the <script> tag in the head so that it'll solve the problem.